# How can I log out of Asana without being logged out of all my google accounts?

Tags: asana

I have 2 different Asana logins, one personal and one work, each using Google auth with a different email address.  If I want to switch from one to another and I click logout, I get logged out of every Google account I'm logged into.

When I emailed support about it, I was told:

> This is actually a completely normal behavior, and part of Google’s security process. When using Google to log into Asana (and a lot of other websites such as Facebook for example), you will automatically be logged out of your Google account, as soon as you log out of Asana. Unfortunately, since this is part of Google security process, there isn’t much we can do to avoid it.

However, I figured out that if I just delete the cookie called `auth_token`, I get taken back to the login screen and I can login to my other account.  As I think through adding Google login to my own sites, is there a reason that services that use Google to login are required to log their users out of Google altogether? This seems to me like very unintuitive behavior to be logged out of a different service.

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you go to https://app.asana.com/-/login, even if you're currently logged in to Asana, you can switch accounts to a different Google account provided (if I recall correctly) you *are* logged into multiple Google accounts. (I think if you're logged into only one account, Google will immediately redirect and log you back into Asana). Give this a try and see if it works!

Comment: This works! Even Asana's Twitter staff didn't have this answer! Thank you!